# Oracle Recover Clob data after truncate table

Tags: oracle, truncate, clob, recover

Is there any way to recover a table that contains CLOB data after truncation? I have accidentally truncated PROD data and would like to recover it back.

Answer (score 1):

Truncate removes all data from a table without recording a delete transaction. There is no way to recover that data with a rollback or "as of" query. The only way to recover your data would be from a backup of the database - either a datapump dump or RMAN backup - made before the truncate command was issued.